# Rails referencing parent id during csv import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, foreign-keys

Firstly, I'm really sorry to ask such a basic question but I'm very new to Rails, Ruby & development in general and my lack of terminology understanding means that I am having a hard time finding the answer to this question.

I am importing a csv of vehicle data using:

```
def self.import(file, category_id)
CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  Model.where(
  :category_id => category_id, 
  :name => row[1],
  :cap_id => row[10] 
  ).first_or_create do |record|
    record.layout = row[3],
```

... several records later ...

```
    record.manufacturer_id = Manufacturer.where(:name => row[0], :category_id => category_id).id
  end
end
end
```

but I am having trouble setting the manufacturer_id with the last line of the loop. I guess you can see what i'm trying to do here but I can't work out how this should be written.

Basically i have a list of manufacturers belonging to different categories (so, for example, there is a Ford manufacturer with category_id=1 (for cars) and another Ford manufacturer with category_id=54 for trucks.

Can I set the manufacturer_id of each record by taking the current category_id and the manufacturer name from the csv, cross referencing them and pulling back the id of the result?

When trying the above code i get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in ModelsController#import
undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Manufacturer:0x007fcd96f744a8>
Extracted source (around line #33):

32      record.description = row[2],
33      record.manufacturer_id = Manufacturer.where(:name => row[0], :category_id => category_id).id
34    end
35    end
36  end
```

Comment: What exactly is the "trouble setting the manufacturer_id"?

Comment: Sorry about that - I have added the error message. I had assumed that the problem would have been more obvious and just a case of my horrible syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object

```
Manufacturer.where(:name => row[0], :category_id => category_id)
```

so when you called `id` on it, it raised an error.  You should call `first` first and then `id`.

```
Manufacturer.where(:name => row[0], :category_id => category_id).first.id
```

Be warned that doing so assumes that you'll always get a manufacturer that matches the condition.  To be more safe, you can use `try`

```
Manufacturer.where(:name => row[0], :category_id => category_id).first.try(:id)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks again jvnill that worked just as I wanted it to.

Comment: You can also use the [pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) function to pick a single column out (like id), instead of returning the entire record.

Comment: Thanks Slicedpan.. I will take a look and try it out!

Comment: @Slicedpan, `pluck` may be used in this case but using `first` is better since that only gets the first record in the db.  If you have a million manufacturers, `pluck` will go through all of them.  If you want to use `pluck`, use it with `limit` or just select the id.

Comment: @jvnill Good point. Selecting the id is a much better solution